# Equivalence of a vector bundle being trivial on $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space

I am looking for various statements about a vector bundle $E$ of arbitrary rank being trivial on the complex projective line, $\mathbb{P}^1$. In particular, some arguments about cohomology would be nice. For example, we know a bundle $E$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is trivial if and only if $H^0(E(-1)) = H^1(E(-1)) = 0$.

What other statements in this same vein are equivalent to the triviality of $E$?

Comment: Do you know Grothendieck's theorem about what the vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1$ look like? They're just sums of the $\mathcal{O}(m)$.

Comment: Yes, that can be helpful, thanks. But since I want the trivial bundle, I'd be looking at just sums of $\mathcal{O}$. I know some stuff probably falls out from, "... if and only if $m_i =0$ for all $i$." I just don't know what.